# myEclipse stuck when building project contained vaadin charts

Tags: vaadin, myeclipse, vaadin7

i have a problem in myEclipse,he stuck when he buiding a project contained vaadin charts add-on libraries.
why he do this?
and what is the solution?
thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "stuck"? It must probably recompile the widgetset, which takes some time depending on your hardware...

Comment: when i open the myEclipse and i open a project conained vaadin charts libraries,he stay on building workspace=12%

Comment: If your workspace has several projects, close the other ones to make sure it's the Vaadin project that is causing the problem. Also, open the progress view (you can usually just double click on the progress bar in the status line at the bottom) to see if you get any more information on what it is building.

Comment: I've done it,the problem due from vaadin project that contained the vaadin charts

Comment: So, your problem is definitely with a Vaadin project that contains Vaadin charts. I'd suggest posting on the Vaadin forum for Vaadin specific help. https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/dashboard